# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare create_initial_rest_routes()

Tags: wordpress

I am facing error with WordPress plugin
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare create_initial_rest_routes() (previously declared in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php:183) in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/rest-api/plugin.php on line 216.

I have 2 plugin having this method 1 is default from WP and another is custom for my site.

Can you please help me about this, what process i am doing wrong here. **As I am a JAVA developer and trying to understand the PHP plugin logic**.

PHP version : 5.3.4

Apache: 2.2.17

MySql:5.1.53

Thanks in Advance.